# Изменить timedText source в MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Нужна помощь.

Есть видеоплеер основанный на *MediaPlayer*. Добавлена поддержка субтитров, но сделать так, чтобы можно было менять путь к файлу субтитров, например по нажатию кнопки менять язык субтитров `player.addTimedTextSource(new_subtitles)` - не помогает.

Я новичек в *Android* разработке, так, что не судите строго.

Поиск решения в сети ни к чему не привел.
Заранее спасибо за помощь!